# Error: Not Found when I am using actions/create-release@v1 in my workflow. Even I tried putting manually still getting the Error

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api, github-for-windows

```
name: Create Release
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'v*'
jobs:
  create_release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: Dev

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Create Release
      id: create_release
      uses: actions/create-release@v1
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      with:
        tag_name: v1.1.8
        release_name: release test last
        draft: false
        prerelease: false
```

I have correctly declared version_tag with the other task. Even given the right access to create release in repo. Still getting the error.